# Cannot access protected member GetService without a python subclass of Document

Tags: .net, ironpython, spotfire

I keep getting this error, "Cannot access protected member GetService without a python subclass of Document" on this line of code ... "progressService = Document.GetService(ProgressService)"

The code below is meant to prompt a save as dialog and save a file to a folder in a certain location.

Here is the code:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")

from System.Windows.Forms import 

MessageBox,Form,MessageBoxButtons,DialogResult

from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import DocumentSaveSettings

from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Library import *

from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel import ProgressService

message="Would you like to save the file"

caption="Save to Library"

reply=MessageBox.Show(message,caption,MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)


def savetoLibrary():

    folderName = r"C:\Users\Documents\NEW"

    fileName = "TESTNEW.xlsx"

    libraryManager = Document.GetService(LibraryManager)

   success, libraryFolder = libraryManager.TryGetItem(folderName, LibraryItemType.Folder)

    settings = DocumentSaveSettings()

    Application.SaveAs(libraryFolder,fileName,LibraryItemMetadataSettings(), settings);


if reply==DialogResult.Yes:

    progressService = Document.GetService(ProgressService)

    progressService.ExecuteWithProgress("Saving to Library", "Saving analysis", savetoLibrary)
```

Set up the Library Manager and ensure that we can access the folder path specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetService for ProgressService and LibraryManager is on the Application instead of the Document. This should work for you, assuming your library is set up on a filesystem instead of the Spotfire database.

If you have the Spotfire Library stored in the Spotfire database, your foldername and filename will look more like '/spotfire/library/path' and 'filename' respectively.

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import MessageBox,Form,MessageBoxButtons,DialogResult
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import DocumentSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Library import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel import ProgressService

message="Would you like to save the file"
caption="Save to Library"
reply=MessageBox.Show(message,caption,MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

def savetoLibrary():
    folderName = r"C:\Users\Documents\NEW"
    fileName = "TESTNEW.xlsx"
    libraryManager = Application.GetService(LibraryManager)
    success, libraryFolder = libraryManager.TryGetItem(spotfireLibraryFolder, LibraryItemType.Folder)
    settings = DocumentSaveSettings()
    Application.SaveAs(libraryFolder,fileName,LibraryItemMetadataSettings(), settings);


if reply==DialogResult.Yes:
    progressService = Application.GetService(ProgressService)
    progressService.ExecuteWithProgress("Saving to Library", "Saving analysis", savetoLibrary)
```